# How to disable the button on the validation error in the page in wpf

Tags: wpf, validation, datatrigger, wpf-4.0

I am having the style trigger like below .

```
    <Style x:Key="ValidationButtonErrorStyle" TargetType="Button"  BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=btnStyle}"   >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I want to add this style trigger to my button , so that when the validation error happens in the page ,

```
    <Button Content="{Binding StringResources.XXXX, Source={StaticResource ResourceStrings}}" 
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ValidationButtonErrorStyle}" 
            Width="150"   
            Command="{Binding XXXX}">
    </Button>
```

then my button should get disabled. if not it should be in enabled state .

I tried the above code samples but no luck. Can any one point me what i am missing or help me how to achieve this .

Comment: where is your button...can you post your complete xaml?

Comment: you say you want to disable the button but nowhere in your code you change the `IsEnabled` property ...

Comment: I have updated above code . But no luck. If there is any other way to try this ?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
<Style x:Key="ValidationErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried this. It is not showing any error but the button is not changing  :(

Comment: I am still thinking How the trigger will be triggered. If this is for text box , i can say "NotifyError" and then my text box will be with style trigger . But How a button will notify this? Am i missed to trigger this ?